# Java Midi - How to get notes from midi whilst it's playing

Tags: java, midi, javax.sound.midi

I've searched for a while now, and can't find an answer for what I want to do.

I want to play a midi file, and display the notes on the screen as it plays. When a note stops playing, it should disappear off the screen.

I can play a midi with a sequencer, but have no idea of how to get the notes its playing, or when it stops playing a note.

I've looked into ControllerEventListeners and MetaEventListeners, but still don't know how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would one Solution be to read the midi file, getting all the notes and their duration, and then run another thread to display the notes? Wouldn't this become out of sync if there's some latency though?

Answer (score 3):

That's what you should do:

You have to implement `Receiver` and then

```
sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
sequencer.open();
transmitter = sequencer.getTransmitter();
transmitter.setReceiver(this);
```

and after that, the next method will be triggered every time an event occurs:

```
@Override
public void send(MidiMessage message, long timeStamp) {
    if(message instanceof ShortMessage) {
        ShortMessage sm = (ShortMessage) message;
        int channel = sm.getChannel();

        if (sm.getCommand() == NOTE_ON) {

            int key = sm.getData1();
            int velocity = sm.getData2();
            Note note = new Note(key);
            System.out.println(note);

        } else if (sm.getCommand() == NOTE_OFF) {

            int key = sm.getData1();
            int velocity = sm.getData2();
            Note note = new Note(key);
            System.out.println(note);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Command:" + sm.getCommand());
        }
    }
}
```

and if you want, you can use this class too:

```
public class Note {

    private static final String[] NOTE_NAMES = {"C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"};

    private String name;
    private int key;
    private int octave;

    public Note(int key) {
        this.key = key;
        this.octave = (key / 12)-1;
        int note = key % 12;
        this.name = NOTE_NAMES[note];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof Note && this.key == ((Note) obj).key;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Note -> " + this.name + this.octave + " key=" + this.key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [FAQ](http://www.jsresources.org/faq_midi.html#note_event_notification).
Connect you own Receiver to the sequencer's Transmitter.

See the DumpReceiver in the [MidiPlayer](http://www.jsresources.org/examples/MidiPlayer.html) for an example.

Comment: This has turned out to be very useful, but would you know how to get the duration of a note? I'm wanting to make a basic midi visualizer that will fade out a square as the note fades out.

Comment: A note stops when you receive a note off event.

Comment: I'm not sure I made my point clear. At the moment I am displaying a coloured square when a note plays. I've made it disappears when I get a note off event. I would like to make the coloured square slowly fade out as the note fades out. Would I be right in assuming that the Receiver doesn't know how long a note will play for? If so, I think I'll have to somehow read the midi file before playing, and use that to calculate the timing. Thanks for all your help, you've been really helpful.

Comment: There are instruments that fade out, and ones that don't. That fading is not affected by the time of the note-off event (except for the much faster fading due to the note-off).

Comment: I understand now, since MIDI needs a soundbank, it's not possible to know if the note is fading out. I guess I could still fade out the colour, if I find an instrument with a nice fade out time. Thank you for all your help. Now I've got the fun part of tinkering with my program, and maybe adding more things, so I can learn more about java.