# How to get Note On/Off messages from a MIDI sequence?

Tags: java, midi, javasound

I am hoping to get notifications of note on/off events in a playing MIDI sequence to show the notes on a screen based (piano) keyboard.

The code below adds a `MetaEventListener` and a `ControllerEventListener` when playing a MIDI file, but only shows a few messages at the start and end of the track.

How can we listen for note on & note off MIDI events?

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.midi.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class PlayMidi {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        /* This MIDI file can be found at..
        https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5B9wDXIGw9lR2dGX005anJsT2M&authuser=0
        */
        File path = new File("I:\\projects\\EverLove.mid");

        Sequence sequence = MidiSystem.getSequence(path);
        Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();

        sequencer.open();

        MetaEventListener mel = new MetaEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void meta(MetaMessage meta) {
                final int type = meta.getType();
                System.out.println("MEL - type: " + type);
            }
        };
        sequencer.addMetaEventListener(mel);

        int[] types = new int[128];
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 128; ii++) {
            types[ii] = ii;
        }
        ControllerEventListener cel = new ControllerEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void controlChange(ShortMessage event) {
                int command = event.getCommand();
                if (command == ShortMessage.NOTE_ON) {
                    System.out.println("CEL - note on!");
                } else if (command == ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF) {
                    System.out.println("CEL - note off!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("CEL - unknown: " + command);
                }
            }
        };
        int[] listeningTo = sequencer.addControllerEventListener(cel, types);
        for (int ii : listeningTo) {
            System.out.println("Listening To: " + ii);
        }

        sequencer.setSequence(sequence);
        sequencer.start();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exit this dialog to end");
        sequencer.stop();
        sequencer.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll be watching to see if there is a better answer than either of the two suggestions that I have, which are clearly less than ideal.

1. edit the midi file to include meta events that match the existing key on/off
2. write you own event system

I don't do a lot yet with MIDI, myself. I only occasionally import MIDI scores and strip out most of the info, converting it to use with an event-system I wrote for my own audio needs (triggering an FM synthesizer I wrote).

Comment: Well the first seems like a complete hack, but to give it due credit it seems to work.  See implementation below.  .. I would not know how to approach the 2nd suggestion.

Comment: *"I'll be watching to see if there is a better answer.."*  If there is, there may well be a bounty in it.

Comment: See also the [MIDI Pianola](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5B9wDXIGw9leGZKemxUWS1KME0&authuser=0) based on the code below, and includes 78 (simplistic) MIDI tracks.  :)  Not sure if I've [got the octaves right](http://forums.aussievapers.com/club-vape-|-off-topic-discussion/30055-any-musicians-about.html#post639931), though. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Here is an implementation of the first suggestion of the accepted answer.  It will present an option pane confirm dialog as to whether or not to add a new track to hold meta events corresponding to the `NOTE_ON` & `NOTE_OFF` messages of each of the existing tracks.

If the user chooses to do that, they'll see Meta events throughout the playback of the MIDI sequence.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.midi.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class PlayMidi {

    /** Iterates the MIDI events of the first track and if they are a 
     * NOTE_ON or NOTE_OFF message, adds them to the second track as a 
     * Meta event. */
    public static final void addNotesToTrack(
            Track track,
            Track trk) throws InvalidMidiDataException {
        for (int ii = 0; ii < track.size(); ii++) {
            MidiEvent me = track.get(ii);
            MidiMessage mm = me.getMessage();
            if (mm instanceof ShortMessage) {
                ShortMessage sm = (ShortMessage) mm;
                int command = sm.getCommand();
                int com = -1;
                if (command == ShortMessage.NOTE_ON) {
                    com = 1;
                } else if (command == ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF) {
                    com = 2;
                }
                if (com > 0) {
                    byte[] b = sm.getMessage();
                    int l = (b == null ? 0 : b.length);
                    MetaMessage metaMessage = new MetaMessage(com, b, l);
                    MidiEvent me2 = new MidiEvent(metaMessage, me.getTick());
                    trk.add(me2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        /* This MIDI file can be found at..
         https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5B9wDXIGw9lR2dGX005anJsT2M&authuser=0
         */
        File path = new File("I:\\projects\\EverLove.mid");

        Sequence sequence = MidiSystem.getSequence(path);
        Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();

        sequencer.open();

        MetaEventListener mel = new MetaEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void meta(MetaMessage meta) {
                final int type = meta.getType();
                System.out.println("MEL - type: " + type);
            }
        };
        sequencer.addMetaEventListener(mel);

        int[] types = new int[128];
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 128; ii++) {
            types[ii] = ii;
        }
        ControllerEventListener cel = new ControllerEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void controlChange(ShortMessage event) {
                int command = event.getCommand();
                if (command == ShortMessage.NOTE_ON) {
                    System.out.println("CEL - note on!");
                } else if (command == ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF) {
                    System.out.println("CEL - note off!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("CEL - unknown: " + command);
                }
            }
        };
        int[] listeningTo = sequencer.addControllerEventListener(cel, types);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int ii = 0; ii < listeningTo.length; ii++) {
            sb.append(ii);
            sb.append(", ");
        }
        System.out.println("Listenning to: " + sb.toString());

        int mirror = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                null,
                "Add note on/off messages to another track as meta messages?",
                "Confirm Mirror",
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        if (mirror == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            Track[] tracks = sequence.getTracks();
            Track trk = sequence.createTrack();
            for (Track track : tracks) {
                addNotesToTrack(track, trk);
            }
        }

        sequencer.setSequence(sequence);
        sequencer.start();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exit this dialog to end");
        sequencer.stop();
        sequencer.close();
    }
}
```

### Implementation of keyboard

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import javax.sound.midi.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class MidiPianola {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    public static final int OTHER = -1;
    public static final int NOTE_ON = 1;
    public static final int NOTE_OFF = 2;
    private OctaveComponent[] octaves;
    Sequencer sequencer;
    int startOctave = 0;
    int numOctaves = 0;

    MidiPianola(int startOctave, int numOctaves)
            throws MidiUnavailableException {
        this.startOctave = startOctave;
        this.numOctaves = numOctaves;
        initUI();
    }

    public void openMidi(URL url)
            throws InvalidMidiDataException, IOException {
        openMidi(url.openStream());
    }

    public void openMidi(InputStream is)
            throws InvalidMidiDataException, IOException {
        Sequence sequence = MidiSystem.getSequence(is);
        Track[] tracks = sequence.getTracks();
        Track trk = sequence.createTrack();
        for (Track track : tracks) {
            addNotesToTrack(track, trk);
        }
        sequencer.setSequence(sequence);
        startMidi();
    }

    public void startMidi() {
        sequencer.start();
    }

    public void stopMidi() {
        sequencer.stop();
    }

    public void closeSequencer() {
        sequencer.close();
    }

    private void handleNote(final int command, int note) {
        OctaveComponent octave = getOctaveForNote(note);
        PianoKey key = octave.getKeyForNote(note);
        if (command == NOTE_ON) {
            key.setPressed(true);
        } else if (command == NOTE_OFF) {
            key.setPressed(false);
        }
        ui.repaint();
    }

    private OctaveComponent getOctaveForNote(int note) {
        return octaves[(note / 12) - startOctave];
    }

    public void initUI() throws MidiUnavailableException {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }
        sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        MetaEventListener mel = new MetaEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void meta(MetaMessage meta) {
                final int type = meta.getType();
                byte b = meta.getData()[1];
                int i = (int) (b & 0xFF);
                handleNote(type, i);
            }
        };
        sequencer.addMetaEventListener(mel);
        sequencer.open();

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

        JPanel keyBoard = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        ui.add(keyBoard, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        int end = startOctave + numOctaves;
        octaves = new OctaveComponent[end - startOctave];
        for (int i = startOctave; i < end; i++) {
            octaves[i - startOctave] = new OctaveComponent(i);
            keyBoard.add(octaves[i - startOctave]);
        }

        JToolBar tools = new JToolBar();
        tools.setFloatable(false);
        ui.add(tools, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        tools.setFloatable(false);
        Action open = new AbstractAction("Open") {

            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(ui);
                if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File f = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    try {
                        openMidi(f.toURI().toURL());
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        tools.add(open);

        Action rewind = new AbstractAction("Rewind") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sequencer.setTickPosition(0);
            }
        };
        tools.add(rewind);

        Action play = new AbstractAction("Play") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                startMidi();
            }
        };
        tools.add(play);

        Action stop = new AbstractAction("Stop") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                stopMidi();
            }
        };
        tools.add(stop);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    /**
     * Iterates the MIDI events of the first track, and if they are a NOTE_ON or
     * NOTE_OFF message, adds them to the second track as a Meta event.
     */
    public static final void addNotesToTrack(
            Track track,
            Track trk) throws InvalidMidiDataException {
        for (int ii = 0; ii < track.size(); ii++) {
            MidiEvent me = track.get(ii);
            MidiMessage mm = me.getMessage();
            if (mm instanceof ShortMessage) {
                ShortMessage sm = (ShortMessage) mm;
                int command = sm.getCommand();
                int com = OTHER;
                if (command == ShortMessage.NOTE_ON) {
                    com = NOTE_ON;
                } else if (command == ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF) {
                    com = NOTE_OFF;
                }
                if (com > OTHER) {
                    byte[] b = sm.getMessage();
                    int l = (b == null ? 0 : b.length);
                    MetaMessage metaMessage = new MetaMessage(
                            com,
                            b,
                            l);
                    MidiEvent me2 = new MidiEvent(metaMessage, me.getTick());
                    trk.add(me2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                                UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                    }
                    SpinnerNumberModel startModel = 
                            new SpinnerNumberModel(2,0,6,1);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                            null,
                            new JSpinner(startModel),
                            "Start Octave",
                            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                    SpinnerNumberModel octavesModel = 
                            new SpinnerNumberModel(5,5,11,1);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                            null,
                            new JSpinner(octavesModel),
                            "Number of Octaves",
                            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                    final MidiPianola o = new MidiPianola(
                            startModel.getNumber().intValue(),
                            octavesModel.getNumber().intValue());

                    WindowListener closeListener = new WindowAdapter() {

                        @Override
                        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                            o.closeSequencer();
                        }
                    };

                    JFrame f = new JFrame("MIDI Pianola");
                    f.addWindowListener(closeListener);
                    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                    f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                    f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                    f.setResizable(false);
                    f.pack();

                    f.setVisible(true);
                } catch (MidiUnavailableException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvalidMidiDataException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class OctaveComponent extends JPanel {

    int octave;
    ArrayList<PianoKey> keys;
    PianoKey selectedKey = null;

    public OctaveComponent(int octave) {
        this.octave = octave;
        init();
    }

    public PianoKey getKeyForNote(int note) {
        int number = note % 12;
        return keys.get(number);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        for (PianoKey key : keys) {
            key.draw(g2);
        }
    }

    public static final Shape
            removeArrayFromShape(Shape shape, Shape[] shapes) {
        Area a = new Area(shape);

        for (Shape sh : shapes) {
            a.subtract(new Area(sh));
        }

        return a;
    }

    public final Shape getEntireBounds() {
        Area a = new Area();
        for (PianoKey key : keys) {
            a.add(new Area(key.keyShape));
        }
        return a;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Shape sh = getEntireBounds();
        Rectangle r = sh.getBounds();
        Dimension d = new Dimension(r.x + r.width, r.y + r.height + 1);
        return d;
    }

    public void init() {

        keys = new ArrayList<PianoKey>();
        int w = 30;
        int h = 200;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int xs = w - (w / 3);
        Shape[] sharps = new Shape[5];
        int hs = h * 3 / 5;
        int ws = w * 2 / 3;
        sharps[0] = new Rectangle2D.Double(xs, y, ws, hs);
        xs += w;
        sharps[1] = new Rectangle2D.Double(xs, y, ws, hs);
        xs += 2 * w;
        sharps[2] = new Rectangle2D.Double(xs, y, ws, hs);
        xs += w;
        sharps[3] = new Rectangle2D.Double(xs, y, ws, hs);
        xs += w;
        sharps[4] = new Rectangle2D.Double(xs, y, ws, hs);

        Shape[] standards = new Shape[7];
        for (int ii = 0; ii < standards.length; ii++) {
            Shape shape = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, w, h);
            x += w;
            standards[ii] = removeArrayFromShape(shape, sharps);
        }

        int note = 0;
        int ist = 0;
        int ish = 0;
        keys.add(new PianoKey(standards[ist++], (octave * 12) + note++, "C", this));
        keys.add(new PianoKey(sharps[ish++], (octave * 12) + note++, "C#", this));
        keys.add(new PianoKey(standards[ist++], (octave * 12) + note++, "D", this));
        keys.add(new PianoKey(sharps[ish++], (octave * 12) + note++, "D#", this));
        keys.add(new PianoKey(standards[ist++], (octave * 12) + note++, "E", this));
        keys.add(new PianoKey(standards[ist++], (octave * 12) + note++, "F", this));
        keys.add(new PianoKey(sharps[ish++], (octave * 12) + note++, "F#", this));
        keys.add(new PianoKey(standards[ist++], (octave * 12) + note++, "G", this));
        keys.add(new PianoKey(sharps[ish++], (octave * 12) + note++, "G#", this));
        keys.add(new PianoKey(standards[ist++], (octave * 12) + note++, "A", this));
        keys.add(new PianoKey(sharps[ish++], (octave * 12) + note++, "A#", this));
        keys.add(new PianoKey(standards[ist++], (octave * 12) + note++, "B", this));
    }
}

class PianoKey {

    Shape keyShape;
    int number;
    String name;
    Component component;
    boolean pressed = false;

    PianoKey(Shape keyShape, int number, String name, Component component) {
        this.keyShape = keyShape;
        this.number = number;
        this.name = name;
        this.component = component;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        if (name.endsWith("#")) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        g.fill(keyShape);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.draw(keyShape);
        if (pressed) {
            Rectangle r = keyShape.getBounds();
            GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(
                    r.x,
                    r.y,
                    new Color(255, 225, 0, 40),
                    r.x,
                    r.y + (int) r.getHeight(),
                    new Color(255, 225, 0, 188));
            g.setPaint(gp);
            g.fill(keyShape);
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.draw(keyShape);
        }
    }

    public boolean isPressed() {
        return pressed;
    }

    public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
        this.pressed = pressed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool! Nicely done. Re "option 2," it would take much explanation and code, starting with a mixer (in the audio sense, not the Java Mixer object) that keeps a running count of processed frames and manages an event queue. Andrew if you want to chat further about it, just let me know. You have a contact email address at your website? Also, maybe it isn't a "hack" to do what you are doing. It might be more of a hack to have a single object being responsible for divergent functionality. Better this way with the cueing handled explicitly? I can't say for sure either way. I'm making this up as I go.

Comment: *"I'm making this up as I go."*  I'm familiar with that feeling. ;) I won't take this further since I'm happy sticking with the first approach.  (It is not intended to be a polished product, so however I can do it easily is fine IMO - and that approach is very easy.)  If I can come up with an MCVE of the keyboard I'll add it as an edit and notify you.. :)

Comment: @PhilFreihofner ..see the edit for a (crude but) complete implementation of what I was trying to achieve (i.e. with 'player piano' keyboard component).

Comment: Neat! Looks good. I'm going to book mark this code for future reference. If you are curious, here are a couple of links with projects where I am using my event system. http://www.java-gaming.org/user-generated-content/members/27722/tanpura141204.jar http://www.java-gaming.org/user-generated-content/members/27722/hexara141130.jar Both are stalled works-in-progress. Right now, am awaiting components in mail to build a new computer to better handle the work. Also want to do Android dev with it. Current computer is from 2004.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner *"Current computer is from 2004."* OMG..  I just replaced a machine built around **4 years ago** because it was getting 'long in the tooth'!

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to get this to work with another project. I wrote a piano score for an old silent film: "Rescued By Rover" from 1905, using Erno Rapee's "Encyclopedia" back when in school in the 1980's. I am about to put it into midi (via finale). It might be neat to see a graphic of the piano keys playing while the film rolls. Your tool might also be useful as a teaching aid for beginning pianists.

Comment: LOL! Yes, a terrible situation. Am really pinching pennies here. The one good aspect: it forced me to revise the audio library several times in order to get the processing really efficient so that my computer could both play sounds (all synthesized on the fly) while running graphics for the game.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner *"The one good aspect: it forced me to revise the audio library several times.."*  Yes, I was previously getting my monitors and PCs several steps behind the current standard just to ensure that I was not stressing the user's hardware, and.. come to think of it, I did demand that the guy not put a graphics card in the current machine (so it is using the ..really crappy, onboard graphics card).  It won't do 'window shadowing' as is, and I miss it about '0 much'. :)

Answer (score 1):

An answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266411/java-midi-how-to-get-notes-from-midi-whilst-its-playing). Something like:

```
class MidiPlayer implements Receiver {
    private Receiver myReceiver;

    void play() {
        Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        ...
        // Save the original receiver
        this.myReceiver = sequencer.getReceiver();
        // Override the receiver
        sequencer.getTransmitter().setReceiver(this);

        sequencer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void send(MidiMessage msg, long tstamp) {
        // Send the message to the original receiver
        this.myReceiver.send(msg, tstamp);

        // Process the message
        if (msg instanceof ShortMessage) {
            ShortMessage shortMsg = (ShortMessage) msg;
            if (shortMsg.getCommand() == ShortMessage.NOTE_ON) {
                System.out.printf("NOTE ON\n");
            }
        }
        ...
    }
```