# Layered Panel GUI

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

I'm attempting to make a keyboard to other instrument tab maker. 
The way I have the piano set up is using a layered panel. The problem I'm having is now whenever I try adding anything else that's separate from the piano itself it doesn't show up or the piano doesn't show up and it will?
So what I'm asking is how would I go about adding an image to the right hand side of the screen while keeping everything else intact? 
Thanks. 
P.s I know the black buttons are messy please ignore that.

[image]

```
class Piano extends JPanel
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        JLayeredPane panel = new JLayeredPane();
        frame.add(panel);

        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        {
            JButton b = new JButton();
            b.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            b.setLocation(i * 20, 0);
            b.setSize(20, 100);
            panel.add(b, 0, -1);
        }
        JButton b = new JButton();
        b.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        b.setLocation(16, 0);
        b.setSize(12, 80);
        panel.add(b, 1, -1);
        //
        JButton b1 = new JButton();
        b1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        b1.setLocation(52, 0);
        b1.setSize(12, 80);
        panel.add(b1, 1, -1);
        JButton b2 = new JButton();
        b2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        b2.setLocation(76, 0);
        b2.setSize(12, 80);
        panel.add(b2, 1, -1);
        //
        JButton b3 = new JButton();
        b3.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        b3.setLocation(112, 0);
        b3.setSize(12, 80);
        panel.add(b3, 1, -1);
        JButton b4 = new JButton();
        b4.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        b4.setLocation(134, 0);
        b4.setSize(12, 80);
        panel.add(b4, 1, -1);
        JButton b5 = new JButton();
        b5.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        b5.setLocation(157, 0);
        b5.setSize(12, 80);
        panel.add(b5, 1, -1);
        //
        JButton b6 = new JButton();
        b6.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        b6.setLocation(192, 0);
        b6.setSize(12, 80);
        panel.add(b6, 1, -1);
        JButton b7 = new JButton();
        b7.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        b7.setLocation(216, 0);
        b7.setSize(12, 80);
        panel.add(b7, 1, -1);
        //
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you put a JPanel with a BorderLayout in the JFrame. Then add your LayeredPane in the Center and another Jpanel with the image to the right.

Answer (score 0):

You essentially want to use a `Layout` for your `JPanel` e.g. a `GridLayout`.

e.g. smth. like this

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));
```

[Here is a example in the oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

Answer (score 0):

By default a JFrame uses a `BorderLayout`.

```
frame.add(panel);
```

When you don't specify a constraint, then "CENTER" is used, so you are adding the layered pane to CENTER of the frame.

If you want to add another panel to the right of the frame then you do something like:

```
JPanel right = new JPanel();
right.add(...);
frame.add(right, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information.

You might also want to check out [Midi Piano](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29318824/131872) for a complete implementation of a piano keyboard with sound, just for fun.