# Piano Keys-- Not overlapping and now not showing up

Tags: java, swing, piano

Note: I'm working with jFugue.

```
public class Piano extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
    ArrayList<Keys> keys = new ArrayList<Keys>();
    Player playNote = new Player();

    public Piano() {
        drawGrid();
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
    }
    public void drawGrid() {
        pane = new JLayeredPane();
        this.setLayout(null);

        keys.add(new Key(new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 300), new Pattern("V0 I[Piano] C5q"), Color.white));
        keys.add(new Key(new Rectangle(25, 0, 25, 180), new Pattern("V0 I[Piano] C#5q"), Color.white));
        keys.add(new Key(new Rectangle(50, 0, 50, 300), new Pattern("V0 I[Piano] D5q"), Color.white));
        keys.add(new Key(new Rectangle(75, 0, 25, 180), new Pattern("V0 I[Piano] D#5q"), Color.white));
        keys.add(new Key(new Rectangle(100, 0, 50, 300), new Pattern("V0 I[Piano] E5q"), Color.white));
        keys.add(new Key(new Rectangle(150, 0, 50, 300), new Pattern("V0 I[Piano] F5q"), Color.white));
        keys.add(new Key(new Rectangle(175, 0, 25, 180), new Pattern("V0 I[Piano] F#5q"), Color.white));
        keys.add(new Key(new Rectangle(200, 0, 50, 300), new Pattern("V0 I[Piano] G5q"), Color.white));
        keys.add(new Key(new Rectangle(225, 0, 25, 180), new Pattern("V0 I[Piano] G#5q"), Color.white));
        keys.add(new Key(new Rectangle(250, 0, 50, 300), new Pattern("V0 I[Piano] A5q"), Color.white));
        keys.add(new Key(new Rectangle(275, 0, 25, 180), new Pattern("V0 I[Piano] A#5q"), Color.white));
        keys.add(new Key(new Rectangle(300, 0, 50, 300), new Pattern("V0 I[Piano] B5q"), Color.white));

        this.add(keys.get(0));

        for (Key w: keys) {

            w.setBounds(w.getRectangle());
            this.getContentPane().add(w);

            w.addMouseListener(w);
            w.setPlayer(playNote);

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Piano yamaha = new Piano();
        yamaha.setSize(1000, 500);
    }
}
```

Here is part of the key class:

```
public class Key extends JLayeredPane implements MouseListener {
    Player player;
    Rectangle rectangle;
    Pattern pattern;
    Color color;

    public Key(Rectangle r, Pattern p, Color c) {
        rectangle = r;
        pattern = p;
        color = c;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect((int) rectangle.getX() - 1, (int) rectangle.getY() - 1, (int) rectangle.getWidth() - 1, (int) rectangle.getHeight() - 1);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect((int) rectangle.getX(), (int) rectangle.getY(), (int) rectangle.getWidth() - 1, (int) rectangle.getHeight() - 1);
        repaint();
    }

    public Rectangle getRectangle() {
        return rectangle;
    }

    public void setRectangle(Rectangle rectangle) {
        this.rectangle = rectangle;
    }
}
```

The first white key will show up in the frame, but none of the others do. I've tried JLayeredPane, OverlayLayout, GridLayout, and a few more.

Can anyone give me some help with this?

Comment: I have edited your post, have removed irrelevant information and have added the Swing tag. Note that you should not be using a JLayeredPane to represent each key, as that's working it backwards. Instead consider using ONE one JLayeredPane and adding components to it. Also don't override the JLayerdPane's paintComponent. Also if you ever do override paintComponent in your other components, always call the super's method and **never** call `repaint()` from within it. Read the Swing tutorials as they won't lead you wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to do custom painting then you would just override the `paintComponent(...)` method of a JPanel. This panel (not the JFrame) should contain your "keys" ArrayList. The `paintComponent(...)` method would then iterate through your "keys" ArrayList to paint each piano key at its proper location.

Check out the `DrawOnComponent` example found in [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for an example of this type of painting approach.

Then for your MouseListener code you would iterate through the "keys" ArrayList in reverse to find the key that contains the mouse point. So you would just use the `Rectangle.contains(...)` method to determine which key was clicked.

Or the other approach is to add real Swing components to the panel. Then you don't have to do any of the custom painting or searching logic to determine which key was pressed. All you need to worry about is the layout of each component.

For an example of this approach check out: [How to create a Piano using JScrollPane and JLayeredPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314733/how-to-create-a-piano-using-jscrollpane-and-jlayeredpane/29318824#29318824)