# Which LayoutManager should I use for positioning images of Piano Keys using Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, layout

I'm trying to create a Piano and I have beautiful images for every different key.

I want a dynamic way of adding the keys at the correct position. Now for the white keys it's pretty easy, I just use FlowLayout and they will be finely positioned. But for the black keys I cannot think of an appropriate dynamic way to add them correctly fitting in the empty spaces between the white keys.

The reason is that the bottom part of the white key is wider than its top part.
Also the distance between the black keys is not fixed, it differs from key to key.

The white key's bottom width is always the same as well as for the top width. Therefore the way I implemented it was cut the white key in top and bottom part and use a JPanel with FlowLayout each and then position these two panels one below the other. That way works but I think it's not optimal since for adding KeyListeners I would end up needing two for just one Key.

Isn't there a better way of adding the black keys?

Comment: Add a tag or mention for the GUI framework you are using. Swing? JavaFX? SWT? Vaadin?

Comment: You will probably find that no-one layout gives you the complete flexibility you need to achieve this result and you might need to consider writing one of your own.  Personally, I would investigate both `GridBagLayout` and `MigLayout`, been the two most flexible managers available, as a starting point

Comment: Thx Brasil, did the changes. @MadProgrammer yeah I love GridBagLayout it's awesome. I thought someone could give me some conceptional hints or ideas to achieve this as I already implemented one working way but it's not really good I think.

Comment: What about boxlayout?

Comment: `...I think it's not optimal...` - I would agree. I would suggest you really should be displaying the black keys over top of the white keys which means you need to 1) have a custom panel for the keys to support painting of the components properly 2) have a custom layout manager to position the black keys on top of the white keys. You may want to check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314733/how-to-create-a-piano-using-jscrollpane-and-jlayeredpane/29318824#29318824.

Comment: The code actually uses a null layout so the keys can be positioned properly, but the logic is dynamic based on the key, so that logic could be implemented in a custom layout manager.